# Loading screen JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have my page using Nvd3 for multiple charts and I would like to add a loading circle on each chart. The problem is when it is done loading data from the server and finish graphing, the circle won't disappear, the JavaScript I'm using is:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
  var load_screen=document.getElementById("load_screen");
  document.body.removeChild(load_screen);
});
```

and on the console I receive error:

> mainController.js:802 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on        'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

I also tried many other JavaScript solutions but they all failed to close the loading circle, maybe it's because Nvd3 retrieving data is not recognized as windows? If I try to load YouTube video page it seems to work perfectly.

```
<div id="load_screen">
    <div class="spinner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the code for loading data from the server for the chart as you mentioned?

Comment: it would seem there is no element with an id of `load_screen` on your page.

Comment: or at least, there isn't one when the js is handled. wait for the window to load first.

Comment: I'm sorry the `load_screen` id is link to the js, and the `"spinner"` class is link to CSS below:`.spinner{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    
    border: 2px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-top:3px solid #f25a41;
    border-radius: 100%;
    
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    
    animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
    from{
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }to{
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use this:

```
    window.addEventListener("load",function(){
      var load_screen=document.getElementById("load_screen");
      load_screen.parentNode.removeChild(load_screen);
    });
```

Comment: I still receiving this error: mainController.js:802 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: what is theload_screen return value?
or have you try to inspect Element of HTML using javascript console?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to log the *object* `load_screen`?
Please logcat it too.

Probably you should call that anonymous function when you finish loading the charts, or try to attach the *listener* to the body instead the window.

Answer (score -1):

Anyway I figured out myself, sort of.

I use jQuery and wrote a  line inside the controller to hide the
h1> div, where I put my spinner in.

But still, thanks!